# Checkbox uncheck for windows 8.1 phone app

Tags: checkbox, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have a control checkbox that allows the app to play sounds (SoundEnableBox) when it is checked.  If they uncheck it I want it to stay unchecked (So I need to programmadigally uncheck the box when the page is reloaded.  The default is set to checked. Every time the page is reloaded it gets checked again.

I tried the following code but it is not working.  Do I need to bind the property? to keep it unchecked?

```cs
 if (GlobalVariables.SoundsEnabled.GlobalBool == false)
 {
      SoundsEnabledBox.Unchecked = true;
 }
```

I know this should be simple but not with windows phone for some reason.

Comment: Where your code is place? in constructor or In NavigateTo?

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah The code is in navigate to:

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a short while I decided to change the default to unchecked and wrote the following logic to correct the issue I was having.

```
            if (GlobalVariables.SoundsEnabled.GlobalBool == false)
            {
                SoundsEnabledBox.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.SoundsEnabled.GlobalBool == true)
            {
                SoundsEnabledBox.IsChecked = true;
            }
```